# Deploying Jersey REST Webservice on Apache Web Server

Tags: apache2, jersey

I am a dot net developer but yesterday I was asked to develop a Restful Web service using Java, I googled a lot and finally I am able to develop, run a "hello world" example using Eclipse+Jersey+Tomcat.

But I wonder how can I be able to deploy it on Apache Webserver,

Please send me a step by step guide considering me a newbie. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Apache webserver does not support the execution of servlets (as e.g. Tomcat does). What you can do is run a Tomcat server and connect it to Apache by using a [JK connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/).

Comment: seems like an anwer to me :) will mark after test, thanks a lot